# Is Teams Developer Portal usable?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Microsoft announced the https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/ portal a couple of months ago as a public preview.
I wasn't able to access it but thought that might be because of the very early nature.
But still today, I only get a blank and empty page and a javascript error:

```
8.67d63b1c.chunk.js:2 ReferenceError: oneDS is not defined
    at Function.value (main.0b85f8d8.chunk.js:1)
    at main.0b85f8d8.chunk.js:1
    at cs (8.67d63b1c.chunk.js:2)
    at Sc (8.67d63b1c.chunk.js:2)
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (8.67d63b1c.chunk.js:2)
    at Ko (8.67d63b1c.chunk.js:2)
    at Oc (8.67d63b1c.chunk.js:2)
    at 8.67d63b1c.chunk.js:2
    at F (8.67d63b1c.chunk.js:2)
    at MessagePort.O.port1.onmessage (8.67d63b1c.chunk.js:2)
```

Is the portal supposed to work?
I tried in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have raised a bug and the concerned team is looking into it.

Comment: Just ping me if I can help somehow

Comment: @MarkusJoschko - could you please check and confirm if you are still getting this error?

Comment: Just checked. It is working fine now.